# Will context-switching happen when thread changes its state?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, context-switching, thread-state

In java, will context switching happen when thread is changing its state?

I've googled a lot of sites, but did't find any article mentioned about this.

so if anyone can help would be appreciated.

like this:

```
doSomething();
//when Thread.sleep() is called, thread state will change from runnable to timed_waiting, so will context switching happen?
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Yes. Most current implementation will tell OS that tread is sleeping and context can be switched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `sleep()` triggers context switching to `TIMED_WAITING`.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TIMED_WAITING